# How to correctly Setup Font sizes / Width of elements depending on Pixel density on Android?

Tags: c#, android, layout, size, maui

I'm currently developing a .Net Maui android application and I've hit a roadblock with FontSizes.

After deploying the app and trying on many different phones I've come to realize that screens with the same size often have different Pixel densities and the Layout just goes crazy depending on Pixel Density and screen size.

For example, Phones with Large screen such as tablets have a smaller "Height" than a normal sized Phone when I check the DeviceDisplayInfo. And the exact same screen size with different pixel density just makes all the layout "shrink".

I'll give you an example with images so you can better understand.

This is a print screen of the app running on an emulator for Google Pixel 5 with "base" specifications:

[image: base density image]

This is a print on the exact same screen also on a Google Pixel 5 but with 560 Pixel density instead of base 440:

[image: 560 density Image]

As you can see in the higher pixel density emulator the whole layout turns out to be too big.

I've tried doing some calculations with ScreenSize(height/width) and Density but came to no final conclusion , it varies wildly depending on screensize and density.

I'm actually able to create specific styles (small/medium/large , for example , using different FontSizes / heights, etc..) for the components of the page and change them dinamically depending on the screensize . This is how I'm doing it.

```
 protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        double ScreenSize = this.Height;
                
        //Also tried doing something like this but wasn't helping me in any way
        //ScreenSize = (DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height /  DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density); 

        if(ScreenSize < 0)
            return;
      

        if (ScreenSize >= 900) 
            SetSizesLarge();
        if (ScreenSize > 600 && ScreenSize  < 900)
            SetSizesMedium();
        if (ScreenSize < 600)
            SetSizesSmall();
    }
    private void SetSizesLarge()
    {
        WelcomeHeaderLabel.Style = ResourceHelper.FindResource(this, "ActiveHeaderStyleLarge") as Style;
        Go_Natural_Bottom_Logo.WidthRequest = (double) 200;
        
    }
    private void SetSizesMedium()
    {
        WelcomeHeaderLabel.Style = ResourceHelper.FindResource(this, "ActiveHeaderStyle") as Style;

        Go_Natural_Bottom_Logo.WidthRequest = (double)150;
    }
    private void SetSizesSmall()
    {
        WelcomeHeaderLabel.Style = ResourceHelper.FindResource(this, "ActiveHeaderStyleSmall") as Style;

        Go_Natural_Bottom_Logo.WidthRequest = (double)120;
    }
```

So, how do I know when to use a Small /Medium / Large  Layout depending on the phone Size/pixel density?